# Can I adjust the button styles of Chrome's <input type="date"> datepicker?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-input

Is there any way to change the input type="date" styles from Chrome's default styles? I want to replace the circle button to something else.

The circle button selects today's date.

[image: Example of HTML date field in Chrome]

Comment: What circle button? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: between the arrows - http://cdn.sixrevisions.com/0345-07_date_input_type_example.jpg.

Answer (score 0):

The circle button you mention is native to Chrome, it doesn't appear in Firefox or IE11 (see [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime) for reference). You might want to consider using something like [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) instead for cross browser support.